# change keyboard language by API in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to vb.net and I'm supposed to change the keyboard language to Farsi(Persian) by using API functions while the program is running( It's a plain form with a text box). Does anybody know what should I do? 
Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi butterfly. Welcome to Stack Overflow.
You're more likely to get useful answers to your question if you edit your question to include more details about the problem you're having and what efforts you've made to solve it yourself including any code you might have written

Comment: Hi Crippledsmurf, thanks for the useful advice.

Answer (score 4):

Its very easy. no need to use api its build in to the .net framework.

```
Dim TypeOfLanguage = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa") ' or "fa-IR" for Farsi(Iran) 
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(TypeOfLanguage)
```

[More info on localization..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647353.aspx)

Comment: Actually I was supposed to change the language by using API function. So I used LoadKeyboardLayout function to do so. LoadKeyboardLayout("00000429", 1) Anyway, thanks for the useful information.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim TypeOfLanguage = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa") ' or "fa-IR" for Farsi(Iran) 
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(TypeOfLanguage)
```

This is working fine without the need to use any APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice, but **InputLanguage** does not seem to work with WPF. InputLanguage is a Windows Forms type.

Answer (score 0):

I created a prog which send character to another app by using command My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("en-US text", True) but sometime current input language is not en-US then all character sending are incorrect.
After study from Ezi word, I was solved by modify something like these:
Thanks to Ezi.

```
Private Sub ipl(lg As String)
    Dim TypeOfLanguage = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lg) ' or "fa-IR" for Farsi(Iran) 
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(TypeOfLanguage)
End Sub

Private Sub swlg() 'switch language TH-US
    If InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.Name <> "en-US" Then
        Do
            ipl("en-US")
        Loop Until InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.Name = "en-US"
    End If
End Sub
```